# Event emitting but parent not listening

Tags: javascript, laravel, events, vuejs2, inertiajs

---

**[Edit]:**
I ended up just using Vuex and it works fine with this method.

---

I am having trouble with catching an event.

If I look in the vue dev tools, the event is being emitted but the parent function is not being activated. I have this problem any time I try to use emit throughout this whole project. I am trying to avoid Vuex because this is a Vue/Inertia.js/Laravel stack with all login data and vars being passed from controllers and Laravel session, so I feel like adding Vuex would be redundant.

I'm sorry I can't post the full code because it is for work and I signed an NDA, but if more parts are needed I can provide snippets.

**PARENT** (`<Collection>`)

```
<CollectionFooter v-if="itemsSelected > 0"
:itemsSelected="itemsSelected" @modifySelected="modifyItemsSelected(operation)" />
```

```
data(){
  return {
    itemsSelected: 0
  }
},
```

```
methods: {
   modifyItemsSelected(operation){
      if(operation === "add") {
         this.itemsSelected += 1;
      } else {
         this.itemsSelected -= 1;
      }
      console.log(this.itemsSelected)
   }
},
```

**CHILD** (`<CollectionItemCard>`)

```
<button v-if="active" color="sm-white" @click="changeState">added</button>
<button v-else color="sm-yellow" @click="changeState">add</button>
```

```
methods:{
  changeState(){
    this.active = !this.active;
    let operation;

    if(this.active) {
      operation = "add";
    } else {
      operation = "remove";
    }
      this.$emit('modifySelected', operation);
    }
},
```

vue dev tools screen [image]

Comment: you should use vue dev tools to inspect is the event fire or not?

Comment: Hey Sachin, I just updated the post with a screenshot from dev tools.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this has to do with how you're capturing the payload in the event, but lemme poke around.

Comment: If it helps, I get the same result if I throw @modifySelected to a <template> instead of inside that CollectionFooter component.

Comment: I just looked over your screenshot again– The screenshot says that the event is emitting from `<CollectionItemCard>`, not `<CollectionFooter>`. Can you verify that you're listening for the event on the right component?

Comment: The chain is kind of odd. So there is a counter inside `<CollectionFooter>` which shows the total number of `CollectionItems` clicked. The button to increase/decrease this number is inside `<CollectionItemCard>`.

So it would be Collection -> [ CollectionItemCard , CollectionFooter]
I want `<CollectionItemCard>` -> `<Collection>` -> `<CollectionFooter>`

Comment: Do you have handlers and emitters in each of the intermediate components? When you listen for an even with `v-on` in Vue, you're listening for the event on that specific component exclusively; you won't catch any events from its children.

Comment: Ah... well this probably would have been the answer... moving `@modifySelected="modifyItemsSelected(operation)"` to the `<CollectionItemCard>` component. I will refer to this comment as the answer. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As zcoop98 mentioned above,
moving `@modifySelected="modifyItemsSelected(operation)"` to the `<CollectionItemCard>` component was the key.
I had to have the listener on the **same** component which emitted. Not just *any* parent element.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR – The problem is the way you've written your inline handler.**

Change `modifyItemsSelected(operation)` to just `"modifyItemsSelected"` or `"modifyItemsSelected($event)"`, and you should be good to go. Detailed explanation as to why is below.

---

### Vue Event Handler Rundown

There's two ways to handle events using `v-on` in Vue: *Inline* Handlers, and *Method* Handlers. It's really easy to miss the difference, but it's important.

#### Inline Handlers

[Inline handlers](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Listening-to-Events) are probably what you're most familiar with, since it's exactly what you're using in the example.

This handler type is exactly what it sounds like: you pass a bit of JavaScript *inline* to `v-on`, and Vue runs this code when the event is handled.

For example:

```html
<button @click="alert('Hi!')">Click Me!</button>
```

When the `click` event is emitted by this button, the code `alert('Hi!')` is run, just as it's written.
This is the key to your problem– it runs just as its written, *references and all*.

In your event handler:

```html
<CollectionFooter 
  ...
  @modifySelected="modifyItemsSelected(operation)"
/>
```

You've told Vue to run `modifyItemsSelected(operation)` when `modifySelected` is handled. The problem is that **you've given the inline function an argument which doesn't exist**.

Instead of reading in the *payload from the event* as a variable called `operation`, Vue interprets this syntax as a call to `modifyItemsSelected` with *some existing variable* named `operation`.

Vue goes looking for `operation` in the template context, and then in your component context, and when it doesn't find it, it throws an error, killing execution of the handler.

#### Method Handlers

[Method handlers](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Method-Event-Handlers) are also just what they sound like: instead of passing an inline snippet of JavaScript to `v-on`, you pass it a defined *method name*, only, which Vue binds the handler to directly. A crucial difference between this type and inline is that you **don't include arguments in the call**– Vue handles the argument passing implicitly.

This means that your provided example simply becomes:

```html
<CollectionFooter 
  ...
  @modifySelected="modifyItemsSelected"
/>
```

The payload will be passed as an argument (or arguments, you can pass as many as you'd like into `$emit()`) to `modifyItemsSelected` for it to use.

#### A Note on `$event`

A final thing worth mentioning is some special Vue syntax: [`$event`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Methods-in-Inline-Handlers). This is a placeholder you can use in inline handlers to signify the event payload.

Using `@event="myHandler($event)"` will pass the event payload as the first argument to `myHandler`. This is especially useful when you need some crucial data only accessible from the template in your event handler (eg. in a `v-for` loop), because it allows you to pass *both* the event payload *and* custom data into your handler function at once. (Eg. `@event="myHandler($event, element.index)"`)

This means there's another way to format your event handler and have it work (purely a matter of preference in this case):

```html
<CollectionFooter 
  ...
  @modifySelected="modifyItemsSelected($event)"
/>
```

#### Snippet Example

Finally, here's an example to illustrate this information dump.

Three buttons, all calling the same method a different way. The given method simply prints a message and the (stringified) event to console.

Clicking the button with your current handler throws an error into the console, without printing anything (the development version of Vue is nice enough to give a warning and still print, but the production version isn't so kind). The other two print successfully.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    foo(e) {
      console.log('Handled!');
      console.log('Event:', JSON.stringify(e));
    },
  },
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 85px !important; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="foo(bar)">Inline Handler:</button><span><code> @click="foo(bar)"</code> (Your example code)</span>
  <hr>
  <button @click="foo">Binded Handler:</button><span><code> @click="foo"</code> (Alternative #1)</span>
  <br><br>
  <button @click="foo($event)">Inline Handler w/ $event:</button><span><code> @click="foo($event)"</code> (Alternative #2)</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Althought this probably would solve the problem of passing the argument which I would likely run into next :), I still get a blank console when the event triggers, even if I change (operation) to ($event). The console should return (this.itemsSelected). Even a console.log('hello') shows nothing.

Comment: I also get nothing if I use it as a method handler as you wrote (without inline arguments). An error would be great, but it's just blank.